# Deploy Shiny App on production environment?

Tags: r, shiny

I want my shiny app to be deployed on client system but I want to make sure that client cannot decrypt/view the algorithm or source code . I have been reading a lot on this but got no solution to this. I do not have the option to run it on my server and then make the client hit this as an api. I have to run code in client environment ??

Can anyone guide me how can I do it while maintaining the IP of algorithm ?

Comment: Publish to aws or google and serve it as an `iframe`. At this point I doubt there are any options for you to hide the code once you deploy it on someones server

Comment: Or hire a lawyer to draft a contract that will say that regardless of where the code is, the code is yours.